# Google play distribute app for specific (test) users only

Tags: android, google-play

Simple question, as i can remember there was an option at the developers console in the Play Store to make an app only visible to a set of email addresses. Or at least the app would be free for that set of emails.

So is there an option to make an app only visible to a specific set of email addresses on the Play Store?

I'm asking this because i want to test my app, therefor i have to email it to like 50 people (not a problem). But when i update the app in the "beta" stage i don't want to resend those emails, and ask the test users to update the current install. Using the Play Store updates would be more seamless and automatic.

Does anyone have experience with this situation?

**Edit:**

It seems that there is at the moment only one simple answer:

No, using Google Play it's not (yet) possible. But there are some alternatives out there, see accepted answer.

It would be great if Google could add this functionality to the developers console, this would allow developers to simply bring out new updates, and easily see crash rapports without having to publish the app in public.

**Edit 2:**

Now it is possible to Alpha and Beta test your applications! I believe since the 15 of may 2013.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=nl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play now has alpha and beta testing built in:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Googles own docs say there is a limit of 50 groups containing maximum 2000 users for closed beta distribution (per track). Is this per-track limit applied for a single published app or for all apps under a developer account. Where might I get the official line from Google ?

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't remember seeing the option you mentioned, specifying email addresses for private delivery and therefore, I have no experience on that matter. In fact, a quick check in the Developer Console, revealed that the option is no longer available, which I am sure you already know since you posted a question for the same.

That being said, there is a web service I am aware of (never used it personally, but is recommended by quite a few of my developer friends and colleagues).

The website is: [The Beta Family](http://thebetafamily.com/). A cursory look at their website so far hasn't mentioned any fees or payments for creating an account or uploading an app for testing.

They also have the email feature you mention in the OP which they call *SuperSend* where you specify a set of email addresses and the app is delivered to them.
You can get more information about the same here: http://thebetafamily.com/supersend/

It may not be useful if you are looking specifically for a solution with Google Play. But if you open to alternatives, I think this looks promising.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Their [FAQ's](http://thebetafamily.com/faq/for-developers#what-does-your-service-cost) mentions that their service is, in fact, **free**.

Comment: I have seen the beta family site before and it looks promising indead, going to take a look at it now.