# Is there a site that will download my APK and give me feedback before I publish?

Tags: android, apk, alpha, beta-testing

I have my friends and "alpha testers" but I would love to expose it to as many people as possible before I publish it for the first time in the Google Play store.  If there is something else people recommend, please do tell.

This is my very first app so I am just trying to do my due diligence before publishing and not release before it is ready.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208844/450534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

[Android Tapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/)

[The Beta Family](http://thebetafamily.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ACRA](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/acra/&ei=VR4uUcXeLtDS4QSXo4HIDg&usg=AFQjCNF1L9fawVNYyKuqqIa7q22TBcL08w&sig2=o2-yoO44CxH7LuMALVkDnw) for crash reporting. It's easy to set up and will save you a lot of troubles.
Also, you can host the APK file on any webspace and point your testers to the link. I recommend using Google drive because it's easy to revoke the permissions later.