# Does Google Play place my application to Top New page in the country I just added to distribution list

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my application in Google Play for a certain country to have some statistics and feedback.
When it's improved I'd like to publish it worldwide. But I'm afraid my app will lose a chance of being placed in Top new free listing at Google Play.

So does Google Play place my application to "Top New" page in the country I just added to distribution list?

I failed to google an answer so it would be great if anyone here knows.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be a question also for Android Enthusiasts: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this a programming problem? ;)

Comment: MaciejGórskiless
Nope but here is a lot of questions like this. f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208255/google-play-distribute-app-for-specific-test-users-only

Comment: In android.stackexchange.com, the description for **google-play** tag says *"For questions related to Google's official content store for Android devices. Please note that questions related to publishing, registering, or otherwise interacting with the Play Store in a development capacity are off-topic."* So I guess this is so far the best place to ask this question. Could this be reopened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody knows for sure what qualifiers Google uses to place apps in the top category, so I sincerely doubt you'll get a canonical answer here. You could try writing directly to the Google Play team, but I wouldn't rate your chances of getting a response very high.

AFAIK though, Top New categories are only for apps which were recently published, and not recently adding a country. Moreover, you need a minimum amounts of download in a quick time (1 day? 1 week?), and good ratings overall to get listed in the Top New Free section.